# Ayuda con Automata de Pila en C

Tags: c, pilas

estoy desarrollando un trabajo sobre autómatas  y no me queda claro la aplicación de la pila en este.

no quise acudir a esta pagina ya que quería solucionar mis dudas por merito propio, pero debido al tiempo y a complicaciones no pude, así que agradecería cualquier ayuda.

el problema completo consiste en que tengo que identificar dentro de un archivo de texto ciertas enfermedades representadas mediante el siguiente formato.

cancer -> ***B^N D^2N U^N H^3N***

diabetes -> ***U^2N D^N B^N H^2N***

hepatitis -> ***U^2N D^N H^N B^3N***

Ejemplo: ***BDDUHHH UUUUDDBBHHHH UUDHBBB DDDUUUHHB***

cada una de estas representa la probabilidad de una persona de tener esa enfermedad, en este ejemplo anterior habría 25% de probabilidad de cada una de las enfermedades ya que también hay una palabra que no pertenece e igual cuenta para el total (***DDDUUUHHB***), por ende serian 4 cadenas con solo 3 validas.

toda la lógica ya la tengo solucionada, pero no se representarlo mediante el uso de una pila, agradeceré cualquier consejo, ayuda o lo que sea que puedan decirme al respecto.

Comment: Nunca se me dio bien  la teoría de lenguajes, pero me parece que ese lenguaje no es independiente del contexto, por lo que no se podría procesar con un autómata de pila. Que alguien me corrija si me equivoco, lo estoy diciendo un poco de cabeza.

Comment: @DavidMasedaNeira Asumo que si existe un _alfabeto_ y un conjunto de estados, es posible procesarlo con Automatas de Pila.

Comment: @NaCl no tiene por que. Un autómata de pila tan sólo puede procesar lenguajes independientes del contexto. Para jerarquías superiores los autómatas de pila son insuficientes.

Comment: Tienes razón. De todas formas, el usuario no ha prestado atención a su pregunta en varios días y es muy dificil resolver su duda sin más conocimiento al respecto.

Comment: Habia solo una respuesta y no me sirvió de mucho, he estado intentando solucionarlo pero también tengo otros trabajos, de todas formas gracias por el interés de ayudar.

Comment: Cual es el formato

cancer -> B^N D^2N U^N H^3N ??? B+ D{2,}  U+ H{3,} ???

diabetes -> U^2N D^N B^N H^2N

hepatitis -> U^2N D^N H^N B^3N

Ejemplo: BDDUHHH UUUUDDBBHHHH UUDHBBB DDDUUUHHB

Yo lo conozco de otra forma puedes explicarlo para poderte ayudar